# boto3 Access Denied S3 put_object with correct permissions

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

First time boto3 user.

I had a user with ACL S3FullAccess and used the following code to try and upload a file; it uses a pandas DataFrame as the source.

```
        s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
        io = StringIO()
        df.to_csv(io)
        response = s3_client.put_object(
            Bucket=self.bucket,
            Body=io,
            Key=self.filename
        )
```

This lead to this response

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
```

So I checked that the secret key and access key were being picked up by boto3 from my ~/.aws/credentials file, and they are, on line 604 of client.py in boto3 - request_signer=self._request_signer

So I researched here on SO, and it seemed a lot of people had to add a Policy document, so I did that as follows:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "Policyxxx",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmtx1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<12 digit id>:root"
        },
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:PutObject"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<my-bucket>/*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Stmtx6",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<12 digit id>:root"
        },
        "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<my-bucket>"
    }
]
}
```

I still get the same error, so I added this to my put_object call since the S3 bucket uses AES-256 encryption, which I thought was server-side only, but running out of ideas, so worth a try.

```
            SSECustomerKey=os.urandom(32),
            SSECustomerAlgorithm='AES256',
```

Next I removed those terms associated with the SSE keys, realising that the AES-256 encryption is server side and should not affect my access.

Then I tried to generate a new pair of Access keys and use those instead, same result.

Does anyone have any idea what I might look at next, what have I missing in the hundreds of pages of AWS documentation?

Comment: Are you sure your credentials are set to the same region as those of the bucket?

Answer (score 0):

This was simply a case of when the user was created they were added to a couple of groups. Administrators and EC2MFA.  I was unaware of the implications of this, but assume the EC2MFA group prevented API or CLI access. I am assuming the combination of the Policy on the user and S3 side is sufficiently secure.